# Deploy FrontEnd and BackEnd in two separate services on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, deployment

I have two application that I need to deploy on GCP.

One is the back end API that runs on port 8080 on localhost, and the other is the front end that runs on port 4200.

I have dockerize the 2 application and upload in the GCP, and create a separate service for each of them, but it does not comunicate with each other. Am I missing something?

Locally, I run this docker-compose and runs perfectly.

```
version: "1.0"
services: 

  backend: 
    image: spring-backend:1.0 
    container_name: backend-app 
    ports:
      - '8080:8080' 
    networks: 
      - compose-bridge 

  angular: 
    image: angular-frontend:1.0 
    container_name: solution-angular 
    ports: 
      - '4200:80' 
    networks:
      - compose-bridge 
    depends_on:
      - backend  

networks:
  compose-bridge: 
    driver: bridge
```

I have tried creating 2 separete service, one for each container e run separately, but without success.
I tried to generate a unique container from the 2 application that I need to run, since the GCP does not accept a docker-compose.yml file, but without success too.

Comment: In which service are you running this?

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you want to achieve, and your assumption, is wrong: the FrontEnd never communicates with the backend, not directly.

Take a step back:

- Your front end serves Javascript Angular static files that run in your browser
- Your backend receive request and provide response.

The communication is done between your browser and the backend!!

---

That's being said, you have to deploy each container on Cloud Run. Take care to correctly specify the port that you use (8080 and 4200).

Then, the front end must know the Cloud Run backend URL. But, if your do that, you will have CORS issue.

The best solution is to create a load balancer, with serverless NEG; one for the frontend and one for the backend.

Finally, you have to define the routing rule: which path will reach the frontend, which one will reach the backend (`/api` ?)

And maybe you will have to translate the `/api` on the backend, to `/` because the base path on the backend is not `/api`. If so, with the HTTPS load balancer, you can rewrite the path to solve that issue.

---

As you can see, it's possible, but it's not really straight forward and out of the box.

If you have issues, let a comment, or update your question, I will update my answer.